# Hide Button In ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I have a button which receive permissions in runtime. When user clicks that button, popup opens and user can give permission to read contacts.

When user give the permission, button should be hidden and users must be listed.

But when list is creating, hidden buttons come back. How can i delete them? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

## FRAGMENT

```
boolean granted = checkContactPermission();

        if(granted){
            permissionButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            permissionText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            ArrayList contacts = getContacts(getActivity());

            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(getActivity(), R.layout.contactpage_layout, R.id.test, contacts);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

## LAYOUT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/permissionText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/permissionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="200dp"
        android:text="Permission"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contactListview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"/>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the visibility in your parent Fragment, you need to set the visibility for each particular cell in your adapter when you override `getView()`.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit? I didnt understand what you mean

Comment: Sure. In your code you have just created an implementation of a standard ArrayAdapter, which is only capable of inflating and displaying a layout in each cell, and doesn't know whether to show or hide the button or do any custom behaviour. You need to create your own custom ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter (extends) and define the logic for how you display each cell (i.e. visibility of buttons) by overriding the getView() method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom BaseAdapter for your listView instead ArrayAdapter,

maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26901747/3542143) could help you

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);
        holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.text1.setText(items.get(position).getText1());
    holder.text2.setText(ititems.get(position)getText2());
    if(items.get(position).isSelected()){
       holder.text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) //This can be your own Button
    }else{
       holder.text2.setVisibility(View.GONE)
    }

    return convertView;
}
```